what does vercel mean by this "Invalid request: should NOT have additional property `route`. Please remove it"
this is it
i don't really know what that means. Have tried checking if it means my route folder or what exactly.
please help in solving this chatgpt isn't given an adequate response. This is what am getting from google. please if you know share with me thank yougoogle response

Check your app.json for a node called route. another Expo answer Expo answer on node modules Android answer

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

okay so the issue here was the route obj in the vercel.json file I had to remove it and the problem was solve.
here is what it looked like now
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
      {
          "src": "./index.js",
          "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
  ]
}

but a new one was reborn which I posted help out if you find it THANKS 
